# Different definitions of monad, again.

Tags: notation, category-theory, monads

In

- Moggi, Eugenio, [Computational lambda-calculus and monads](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.3678&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1989): page 2.

A monad over a category $\textbf{C}$ is defined as a triple, $(T, η, µ)$, consisting of the natural transformations $T: \textbf{C} \rightarrow \textbf{C}$, $\eta: Id_{\textbf{C}} \rightarrow T$ and $µ: T^2 \rightarrow T$ for which the following equations hold:

$$(i) \hspace{0.3cm}µ_{TA} ; µ_A = T(µ_A);  µ_A$$
$$(ii) \hspace{0.3cm}η_{TA} ;µ_A = Id_{TA} = T(η_{A}); µ_{A} $$

However, I am confused by what the semicolon is denoting in $(i)$ and $(ii)$, and by what the equations mean, since Moggi has not defined what is meant by $µ_{TA}$, $µ_{A}$, $id_{TA}$, etc. Does he simply mean by $µ_{TA}$, the application of $µ$ to $T$ and $A$?

The same mysterious semicolon notation is used in his definition of a Kleisli Triple.

I'm having trouble relating $(i)$ and $(ii)$ to the following 'coherence conditions' (which I take $(i)$ and $(ii)$ to express):

$$(i') \hspace{0.3cm}\mu \circ T\mu = \mu \circ \mu T \hspace{0.4cm}(\text{as natural transformations} \hspace{0.2cm} T^{3} \rightarrow T);$$ 
$$(ii') \hspace{0.3cm}\mu \circ T \eta = \mu \circ \eta T = 1_{T}\hspace{0.4cm}(\text{as natural transformations} \hspace{0.2cm} T \rightarrow T; \text{here} \hspace{0.2cm} 1_{T} \hspace{0.2cm} \text{denotes the identity transformation from} \hspace{0.2cm} T \hspace{0.2cm} \text{to} \hspace{0.2cm} T).$$

Comment: Those look pretty much the same, except circle is replaced by semicolon, the order is reversed, $\mu$ corresponds to $\mu_A$, $\mu T$ to $\mu_{TA}$ and $T\mu$ to $T(\mu_A)$ etc.

Comment: And what do $T \mu$ and $\mu T$ (and $T\eta$ and $\eta T$) mean?

Comment: Did you mean to insert the extra horizontal space after the semicolons? On my browser that messes up the formatting.

Comment: I thought it would make it clearer but if it is the case that it helps you answer the question I will get rid of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon here just denotes composition (in reverse order from the usual convention) and the subscripts indicate what object you are evaluating the natural transformations on.  So for instance, $\mu_{TA};\mu_A$ means the composition of $\mu_A:T^2A\to TA$ with $\mu_{TA}:T^3A\to T^2 A$ (which would normally be written $\mu_A\circ\mu_{TA}$).  With this interpretation, the equations (i) and (ii) are exactly the same as (i') and (ii') except that the natural transformations have been evaluated at a specific object $A$.

Comment: So is ' ; ' commutative then (given the reverse notation is used by Moggi)?

Comment: No.  It just is defined by $f;g=g\circ f$.

Comment: The flipped composition is often called "[diagrammatic order composition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/composition#Notation)" and has the nice property that if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ then $f;g:A\to C$ so things compose the way they're drawn. Furthermore, in Moggi's context which is denotational semantics of programs, `;` is often used for sequencing of (imperative) programs and can be denotationally modeled as function composition of state transformers for a simple imperative language. For richer effects, it can be modeled by Kleisli composition, and this is the point of the paper.